# Character Limit On Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input id="post" type="text" style="width:400px;"/>
```

You know when you go to a site, start typing in a textbox, and all of a sudden, your keyboard stops typing stuff because you've reached the character limit?

How can I make that happen for this textbox for 140 chars?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`maxlength`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/maxlength) attribute.

```
<input id="post" type="text" style="width:400px;" maxlength="140" />
```

Comment: for XHTML you would use `maxlength` as all attribute names are lowercase

Comment: @Matty F: Cheers, I was just correcting that as you commented :)

Comment: Nearly a -1 from me - why use an HTML attribute when 20 lines of jQuery will do? >:(

Comment: @RobG: the simplest way is the best:P

Comment: @RobG: I guess I'm just lazy ;)

Comment: Just as a note, if you are wanting to access this property from JavaScript (as I was when I found this answer) it's `maxLength` -- `maxlength` is undefined.

Answer (score 7):

Using the jQuery Limit plugin : http://jsfiddle.net/AqPQT/ (Demo)

```
<script src="http://jquery-limit.googlecode.com/files/jquery.limit-1.2.source.js"></script> 
<textarea ></textarea>
<span id="left" />
```

and

```
$('textarea').limit('140','#left');
```

see also: http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/

If you are looking for a sans-jquery solution, just use the maxlength attribute.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="140" />
```

Comment: +1 Wes, that's handy as it also returns the remaining characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
function limitChars(textid, limit, infodiv) {
    var text = $('#'+textid).val(); 
    var textlength = text.length;
    if(textlength > limit) {
        $('#' + infodiv).html('You cannot write more then '+limit+' characters!');
        $('#'+textid).val(text.substr(0,limit));
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $('#' + infodiv).html('You have '+ (limit - textlength) +' characters left.');
        return true;
    }
}

// Bind the function to ready event of document. 
$(function(){
    $('#comment').keyup(function(){
        limitChars('comment', 140, 'charlimitinfo');
    })
});
```

Comment: I added code tags to your answer and removed the redundant closing `</script>`. You may want to tidy up the indentation though...

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code..

```js
var limitCount;
function limitText(limitField, limitNum)
 {
   if (limitField.value.length > limitNum)
    {
     limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    }
    else
    {
     if (limitField == '')
     {
       limitCount = limitNum - 0;
     }
     else
     {
       limitCount = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
     }
    }
   if (limitCount == 0)
     {
      document.getElementById("comment").style.borderColor = "red";
       }
   else
     {
       document.getElementById("comment").style.borderColor = "";
       }
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" onkeyup="limitText(this,20);" onkeypress="limitText(this,20);" onkeydown="limitText(this,20);" />
```